# What is a "fluid particle" and what is it useful for?

Tags: fluid-simulation

The Blender reference manual talks about a fluid type called ["particle"](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/types/particle.html).

Does anyone know what they are useful for?

Other fluid types like: fluid obstacle, fluid inflow, fluid outflow, are explained nicely.
But I'm having trouble visualizing the use of the type "particle"

Comment: Look at the answer to this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44632/fluid-simulation-real-ocean-waves . Look at the animation then read how it was generated. In steps 3 and 4,  fluid particles were used.

Comment: Oh they are used for foam particles, very nice

Comment: Well, you can also set fire to the particles. Burning oil on the surface of the water, sure!